# AngularJS event on dynamically added button in the pop-up

Tags: angularjs, events, popup

I have a problem with angularJs.
After open the pop-up and dynamically add a button on the pop-up, I don't know how to trigger an button event.
I tried almost 'everything'.

Here is an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/QfnDttJE2OnfHzt65tBQ?p=preview

Comment: you shouldn't be adding things like that in angularjs, you're doing it in jQuery way - adding elements to DOM. Try to set up some array variable on controller which will take a list of your buttons i.e. btnArray (list of objects only) and then do ng-repeat on that btnArray on your button element and show everything from that array on your modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok given your code, it could be improved a bit but this should be solid solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/UiOsyHBjVZTW33yr6h3z?p=preview

Javascript:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance,$compile) {
      var $ctrl = this;
      $ctrl.buttonArray = [];

      $ctrl.cancel2 = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');      
      };

      $ctrl.add2 = function(){        
       $ctrl.buttonArray.push('message' + $ctrl.buttonArray.length)  
        };

      $ctrl.message = function () {
        alert('Message');
      };

});
```

HTML:

```
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="postoviCtrl as $ctrl">

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="modalOdabraniPost.html">

          <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Header</p>
                        <hr/>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.add2()">Add</button>

                        <div id="content">
                          <button ng-repeat="btn in $ctrl.buttonArray" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.message()">{{btn}}</button>'
                        </div>
          </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel2()">Close</button>

            </div>
        </script>

        <a href="" class="label label-danger" ng-click="$ctrl.open2()">Open</a> 

    </div>
```